# Get highest value considered of other attribute

Tags: select, max

I have a requirement for selecting the newest record of each person.

Values in table:

  Date | Person
- 10.06.2013 | James
- 12.06.2013 | James
- 17.06.2013 | David
- 17.06.2013 | Emily

Desired result:

- 12.06.2013 | James
- 17.06.2013 | David
- 17.06.2013 | Emily

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = ( SELECT MAX(date) FROM TABLE )`

The above statement gives me only the records with date "17.06.2013". How do I have to adjust my statement so that the newest entry of each person will be outputed?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by a simple group by.

SELECT Person, MAX(Date) As Date FROM table GROUP BY Person